# Banners inside Nav tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, adsense, banner

I'm trying to put a banner using google ads inside my webapp, in a nav menu but I'm not able to show it. What I only can see is an iframe with an empty body inside it (which means that google ads did his work correctly, but for any reason, the content cannot be visualized).

Does anyone knows if it's possible to put a banner inside a nav menu? I've tried to put other banners in my webapp and all of them are shown correctly.

Thank you,

Comment: What would be special about the nav menu? If it works anywhere it should work there unless there is something unusual about your menu. All your code looks correct.

Comment: I don't know. What I know is that google doesn't allow you to put banners in some special places and I don't know if a nav is one of them.

Comment: Do you use a responsive ad code or a fixed one?

Comment: I'm using responsive code.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the thing was that I was putting the two same banners in the same page, but I didn't see the second one.

So, there is nothing related with nav tag.

Thank you all.

Comment: So the issue was something that cannot be solved just using you description of the problem in your question? Also, you should make it more clear in your question what you're talking about. You would need to include code and maybe an image of the problem. It's not useful to anyone as it is now. Why don't you just delete your question altogether? There's a close reason specifically for those cases: Not reproducible.

Comment: You're right, the problem is that I wasn't able to show any picture of the webpage. I'm sorry